# Linked list with a memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

I am struggling my head with this problem.

If I check my application with `top` command in Linux, I get that `VIRT` is always the same (running for a couple of days) while `RES` is increasing a bit (between 4 bytes and 32 bytes) after an operation. I perform an operation once each 60 minutes.

An operation consists in reading some frames by SPI, adding them to several linked lists and after a while, extracting them in another thread.

I executed Valgrind with the following options:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes -v ./application
```

Once I close it (My app would run forever if everything goes well) I check leaks and I see nothing but the threads I haven't closed. Only possibly lost bytes in threads. No definitely and no indirectly.

I do not know if this is normal. I have used Valgrind in the past to find some leaks and it always worked well, I am pretty sure it is working well right now too but the `RES` issue I can't explain.

I have checked the linked list to see if I was leaving some nodes without free but, to me, it seems to be right.

I have 32 linked lists in one array. I have done this to make the push/pop operations easier without having 32 separate lists. I don't know if this could be causing the problem. If this is the case, I will split them:

```
typedef struct PR_LL_M_node {
    uint8_t                 val[60];
    struct PR_LL_M_node     *next;
} PR_LL_M_node_t;

pthread_mutex_t         PR_LL_M_lock[32];
PR_LL_M_node_t          *PR_LL_M_head[32];
uint16_t                PR_LL_M_counter[32];

int16_t LL_M_InitLinkedList(uint8_t LL_M_number) {
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number], NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Mutex LL M %d init failed\n", LL_M_number);
        return -1;
    }
    PR_LL_M_ready[LL_M_number]      = 0;
    PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number]    = 0;
    PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number]       = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);

    return PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number];
}

int16_t LL_M_Push(uint8_t LL_M_number, uint8_t *LL_M_frame, uint16_t LL_M_size) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);
    PR_LL_M_node_t *current = PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number];
    if (current != NULL) {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }

        /* now we can add a new variable */
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(PR_LL_M_node_t));
        memset(current->next->val, 0x00, 60);                                                                                
        /* Clean buffer before using it */
        memcpy(current->next->val, LL_M_frame, LL_M_size);
        current->next->next = NULL;
    } else {
        PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number] = malloc(sizeof(PR_LL_M_node_t));
        memcpy(PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number]->val, LL_M_frame, LL_M_size);
        PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number]->next = NULL;
    }
    PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number]++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);

    return PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number];
}

int16_t LL_M_Pop(uint8_t LL_M_number, uint8_t *LL_M_frame) {
    PR_LL_M_node_t  *next_node  = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);
    if ((PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number] == NULL)) {
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);
        return -1;
    }

    if ((PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number] == 0)) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);
        return -1;
    }

    next_node = PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number]->next;
    memcpy(LL_M_frame, PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number]->val, 60);
    free(PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number]);
    PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number]--;
    PR_LL_M_head[LL_M_number] = next_node;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&PR_LL_M_lock[LL_M_number]);

    return PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number];
}
```

This way I pass the number of the linked list I want to manage and I operate over it. What do you think? Is `RES` a real problem? I think it could be related to other parts of the application but I have commented out most of it and it always happens if the push/pop operation is used. If I leave push/pop out, `RES` maintains its number.

When I extract the values I use a `do`/`while` until I get `-1` as response of the pop operation.

Comment: Calling `pthread_mutex_unlock` in the init function results in undefined behavior, since the mutex wasn't locked at that point.

Comment: I removed the edit. I will remove unlock and test again

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is, but `return PR_LL_M_counter[LL_M_number];` accesses a shared resource outside of critical sections, which can lead to a race condition and UB.

Comment: @n.m My problem is that after pushing some data and popping them, I have a higher value in RES (top) than before. Should I pass a variable to read that parameter inside the critical section too?

Comment: I don't see a problem here. RES is the amount of memory paged in. Your OS decides what to page in or out and when. VIRT is the total amount of memory, if it doesn't change, you don't have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations do not seem to indicate a problem:

- `VIRT` and `RES` are expressed in KiB (units of 1024 bytes). Depending on how virtual memory works on your system, the numbers should always be multiples of the page size, which is most likely 4KiB.
- `RES` is the amount of resident memory, in other words the amount of RAM actually mapped for your program at a given time.
- If the program goes to sleep for 60 minutes at a time, the system (Linux) may determine that some of its pages are good candidates for discarding or swapping should it need to map memory for other processes. `RES` will diminish accordingly. Note incidentally that `top` is one such process that needs memory and thus can disturb your process while observing it, a computing variant of Heisenberg's Principle.
- When the process wakes up, whatever memory is accessed by the running thread is mapped back into memory, either from the executable file(s) if it was discarded or from the swap file, or from nowhere if the discarded page was all null bytes or an unused part of the stack. This causes `RES` to increase again.

There might be other problems in the code, especially in code that you did not post, but if `VIRT` does not change, you do not seem to have a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you. I am pretty sure that there are some other issues. I am still debugging it but I was concerned about RES value. I didn't know what you explained. Very detailed. I will perform the changes the other users suggested in this part and I will keep working then.

Comment: @Biribu: I suggest reading the `man top` pages. This utility is very well documented and offers many useful options.